# Позиционирование колонок в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Нужно чтоб в подобной структуре колонки размещались  по горизонтали,но они почему-то размещаются по вертикали. В чем проблема?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="some-id">
      <div class="col-md-3">work</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">work</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">work</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">work</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так.

Если вам нужно чтобы они внутри какого то блока размещались по горизонтали то откройте внутри этого блока еще один блок `row`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="some-id">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">work</div>
        <div class="col-3">work</div>
        <div class="col-3">work</div>
        <div class="col-3">work</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ну это я знаю. А при такой структуре почему это не получается? Я просто в видеоуроке смотрел, как у лектора, в идентичном построении колонки получаются в ряд. Не пойму, почему у меня так не выходит...